# Attempted to read or write protected memory System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc()

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In my c# win-forms application, I have changed the following line in Main()

```
Application.Run(new MainMenuForm());
```

as

```
MainMenuForm mainMenuForm = new MainMenuForm();
mainMenuForm.ShowDialog();
```

Is it the cause of the above error? 
Stack trace shows following method causes the exception
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc()

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to enable unmanaged code debugging and setup the Microsoft symbol servers to have any real idea why this bombs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Application.Run on some form because it starts message loop on your main gui thread for WinProc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx

Comment: I changed the code back. Since then I didn't got the Exception. Is it the real cause of my problem? Or any other issues may also exist?